# For the least squares solution to $Y = X\beta$, why are there two ways to derive $\hat{\beta}$ (derivatives and matrices)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $Y= X\beta$, with $X$ having full column rank, then there are two ways to find the least squares solution.

The first is by way of **matrix manipulation** is to multiply both sides by $X^T$, then have:

$$
X^TY = X^TX\beta \implies \hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY
$$

Now, the second is by way of **minimization**:

Recognize that the residual sum of squares can be written as:

$$
RSS(\beta) = (Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)
$$

Differentiating with respect to $\beta$,

$$
\frac{\partial RSS}{\partial \beta} = 2X^T(Y-X\beta)= 0 \implies X^T(Y-X\beta) = 0
$$

This implies that

$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY
$$

again.

My question is, what is it about **multiplying** $X^T$ to both sides in the matrix manipulation case that allows us to "circumvent" the minimization? Is this just a small trick or are there deeper implications?

Comment: You can either use calculus to find a point in a subspace closest to a vector or you can use projection matrices to do it. Either way, you're finding the same answer. :) So you should understand the linear algebra of what is called the *normal equations* (your first displayed equation).

Comment: Why do you think that the differentiation method (that requires some statistics theory about minimising sums of squares) is the more natural way (or perhaps the "proper" way which can be "circumvented") rather than the matrix way which is a standard solution to approximating the solution of $\mathbf Y=\mathbf X \mathbf \beta$?

Comment: @DanRobertson The reason is because for least squares it appears I want to minimize the distance between my $Y$ vector and the column space of $X$. Hence, it seemed more natural for me to think about differentiation rather than just straight matrix manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

By multiplying by $ {X}^{T} $ you basically projected both sides of the equation on the column space of $ X $ and then looked for a solution of the equations.

This is exactly the idea behind Least Squares solution.
If $ b $ isn't in the range of $ X $ find the closest vector to $ b $ which is.